# Minimum number of swap operations to sort an array if swapping of two equal size sub arrays is possible

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array **A[1...N]** of positive integers, you have to sort it in ascending order in the following manner **:** In every operation, select any 2 non-overlapping sub-arrays of equal length and swap them. i.e, select two sub-arrays **A[i...(i+k-1)]** and **A[j...(j+k-1)]** such that **i+k-1< j** and swap **A[i]** with **A[j]**, A[i+1] with **A[j+1]** ... and **A[i+k-1]** with **A[j+k-1]**.

```
Example:
For N=6
6 7 8 1 2 3
Only one operation is needed as after swapping (6 7 8) and (1 2 3 ) sub arrays
we can get 1 2 3 6 7 8 , that is sorted.
```

How can we figure out minimum number of swaps in most effective way ?
**SOURCE:** https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/approximate/swap-and-sort/

Comment: If you decompose the array into runs that occur literally in the final sorted array and assign them numbers representing their rank, then the problem reduces to finding the [minimum number of 1-element swaps to sort an array](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/33509/how-do-i-figure-out-the-minimum-number-of-swaps-to-sort-a-list-in-place)

Comment: The question is interesting but please show your attempt.

Comment: @Niklas B: How do you know you can't do better by making a swap that moves multiple runs together? Also, are you assuming that you can swap runs of different lengths?

Comment: @Douglas yes indeed, I missed the restrictions that the chunks have to have the same size. That makes it hard, I don't have a solution for that scenario. Without that restriction I think one can proof that you never need to swap consecutive chunks together.

Comment: Still might be an interesting heuristic for A\*.

Comment: Any two single elements are "2 non-overlapping sub-arrays of equal length", are they not? Which would reduce this to one of many well known sort algorithms. But perhaps that's not quite in the spirit of the question...

Comment: This question is a distorted piece of https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/approximate/swap-and-sort/ which does not require the solvers to find the minimum number of swaps, but just a low number of swaps. I doubt that finding the minimum is reasonable for a programming competition, but the actual competition problem was sensible. Please do not (partially) copy from programming competitions without stating the source.

Comment: @Niklas B: If you reverse the process, you ask for the ways to reach the most permutations by shuffles of a particular type. You are suggesting that you can reach just as many permutations with k shuffles even if you restrict the shuffles allowed severely. That seems like it will rarely be the case, and I think it doesn't hold here.

Comment: You can reach the permutation of 6 objects which in line form is 365214 in 2 swaps: 1[23][45]6 -> [14]52[36] -> 365214. All runs have length 1, and nothing is in its original place, so it will take you at least 3 swaps (and I think more) to get it back to the identity without combining or breaking up runs.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swaparr(int a[],int l,int r,int n) {
    for(int i=l,j=r;i<=l+n&&j<=r+n;i++,j++)
        swap(a[i],a[j]);
}
int findMax(int a[],int n) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if(a[i] > a[index])
            index = i;
    return index;
}
void sort(int a[],int n) {
    for(int r=n-1;r>;0;r--) {
        int index = findMax(a,r);
        if(index != r) {
            int l = min(r-index-1,index);
            swaparr(a,index-l,r-l,l);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int a[] = {7,23,8,234,3,6,41,334};
    int n = 8;
    sort(a,n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Logic : find the max element in each operation and perform that swap such that maximum element goes to the end.
Do this operation N times reducing array size each time by one and aiming to have max element in each operation.
It doesn't necessary to have N swaps. It performs swaps only if the max element is not in its place.
T = O(n2)